# C# Constructors overloading useless brackets

Tags: c#, constructor

I was writing a small class, and just realised something that triggered me.
Here is what my code looks like:

```
class Foo
{
    public int Value;

    public Foo(Bar bar) : this(bar.Ga) { }
    public Foo(Baz baz) : this(baz.Bu) { }
    public Foo(Qux qux) : this(qux.Zo) { }
    public Foo(int val)
    {
        ...
        this.Value = val;
        ...
    }
}
```

I was wondering if we could replace the empty braces `{ }`, something like:

`public Foo(Bar bar) : this(bar.Ga);`

Comment: Unfortunately, AFAIK the answer is no. I have some constructors like that myself and it's always been bugging me as well.

Comment: A different question could also be whether this is the best design of the code to begin with, a better way might be to define extension methods from Bar, Baz, and Quz, to transition over to Foo, so that neither end of the type chain knows about the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

The syntax mandates a body for the constructor, and the empty braces are the best you can do.